# How to configure SpaceVim to highlight .jenkinsfile

Tags: syntax-highlighting

For vanilla [this](https://gist.github.com/richardsonlima/fd42bf8f34ca4444cc828a34c8093f4c) will work, however, SpaceVim seems is harder for me to configure and tweak. Can .vimrc and ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml live in harmony?

Comment: You might have better luck asking the SpaceVim community; idk how many users we have here that know SpaceVim well. Many full-time vim users avoid SpaceVim precisely because it’s harder to configure or tweak

Comment: Is there an exchange for SpaceVim? Didn't find one

Comment: No, no stackexchange. But they have a site/github, and they may have slack/etc.